# Where to redirect a user when he send a quote?

Tags: design-patterns, user-expectation, information-architecture

I have a web site where professionals can send quotes about their services to whoever need them.

To send a quote is a simple form; my question is: what should happen after the user sends the form? If the person wants keep sending more quotes, they can.

So here is my uncertainty; is it better to just display a message in the same page saying "quote sent successfully" or redirect to the page where the user can keep sending more quotes?

Form looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about customer feedback? Or are users sending short descriptions of the services they offer? Or something else?

Comment: Hi @KenMohnkern no, its not customer feedback, it's what you said: its a description of the services they offer, includes description, fee and deadline.

Comment: Is the form located under a specific listing page for a job, or is this a central messaging system the user is filling out and attaching an email address or whatever to send to whoever they need to?

Comment: Form is located at right side. I have update my question with a photo of that section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go. You could do a thank-you or "quote sent" page, as you said, and leave it up to them to go back and find more jobs to bid on. (My least favorite.) You could include a link back to wherever they'd be sending more quotes from such a page, so the flow would be a loop: *find a job > send a quote > thank you > find another job > etc.* Or, if your users are most likely going to be bidding on several jobs in one session, you could speed up the process for them by putting them back on the search page (or wherever they'd start) and including a message/alert (like [these ones from Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts)) at the top, saying their quote was sent. That way, the flow would be *find a job > send a quote > (thank you and) find another job > etc*.

I would prefer the last option, without having much context around how your site works, but it's up to you to find out what your users would prefer to do.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Nate-Green in that there are a few ways to go.

I think you definitely have to have a "high five" (success) message but if I was trying to increase user interaction/sales/quotes then I would definitely bring up between 2 to 5 live jobs that were requesting quotes.

A bit like Amazon who tell you what other customers purchased after you complete a purchase or what other customers who looked at what you looked at were also looking at <-- sorry about all the looking!

I'm usually following the links on Amazon...and eBay for that matter who show you similar items at the bottom of the page!

If you do decide to show outstanding jobs I would make sure they are visible at the same time as the high five!